# Simulate menu button in older app (Android 2.x) on Android 4.x tablet

Tags: menu

I've got a new Android 4.1 tablet. I am trying to run an old app which was created for Android 2.1 and relies on the menu button.

Can somebody points me to a ready-made application which returns the new menu button? Any idea?

Comment: I don't think this is something you can do with an app. A custom ROM might work, but apps (to my knowledge) can't alter the menu bar on a system-wide basis. You'd either need a ROM that supports this as a configuration option (or a modified framework for your current version of Android, possibly) or you'd have to alter the original app to properly support newer Android versions, most likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a newer device loads an app that targets an old Android version, it displays a menu button on the system bar, near the home, recents, and back buttons. It has the same "three dots" icon that you see on newer Android apps. Pressing this has the same effect as pressing the menu key on a device that has one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! The three dots were so tiny I couldn't see them.

Answer (score 2):

On my S6 Edge plus (just upgraded from an S4), I found a long press on the back button solved it.

Comment: Yeap back button worked for me on Samsung S2